# Difference in results between browsers for a transform at the right edge of the page

Tags: css, css-transforms

I find myself in front of a difference when it comes to transform text at the right edge of a page. It seems Chrome(left) and Firefox(right) disagree on the right behavior:

[image: Difference]

this is the transform:

```
'style': {'transform': 'rotate(-90deg) translateY(-305%)','transformOrigin': 'right top', 'textAlign': 'left'}
```

```
element.style {
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(-305%);
    left: 99.3471%;
    transform-origin: right top;
    text-align: left;
}
<style>
.rc-slider-mark-text-active {
    color: #666;
}
<style>
.rc-slider-mark-text {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #999;
}
<style>
.rc-slider * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

^One of the elements behaving differently.

Any thoughts on fix for the left behavior? Thx in advance.

Comment: can you give us a full example? does the parent have `position: relative`?

Comment: Edited to add more details on the css elements.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like adjusting width to fit the content fixed the issue.